# databinding generated class tries to import directory as class

Tags: android, data-binding

Android studio throws:

> "error: cannot find symbol class Database"

while compiling for data binding.

The generated binding class tries to 
`import com.example.myproject.Database;`
where Database is actually a directory not a class.

in layout `xml`:

```
<data>
    <variable name="user" type="com.example.myproject.Database.Entities.User"/>
</data>
```

Directory structure is:

`com -> example -> myproject -> Database -> Entities -> User.java`

If I move User.java to myproject directory the error goes away but I want to retain my directory structure for the code.

I am using Android Studio 3.2 Canary 3.

Please help me if you know how to fix this issue.

Comment: Have you tried to clean your project then rebuild it ?

Comment: Yes, I still get the same error.

Comment: It is an unusual error . I have installed 3.0.1 . I have created exactly the same as your structure and everything works fine . Perhaps in 3.2 C3 has some issue or your error is not related about your structure maybe somewhere else . Try to rename your entire package name to lower case , except class . It was my last hint .

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!  Mehdi Jahed Manesh, going with lower case names for directories solved the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to rename your entire package name to lower case , except class .